# Cambiar id de elemento clonado con jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente código, donde tengo un div id=padre y un div  id=hijo

```
<div class="row p-0 m-0" id="padre">
  <div class="row col-12" id="hijo">
    <div class="col-md-4 pr-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $this->Form->control('masked_start_date', 
                                            ['name' => 'start_date', 
                                            'id' => 'datetimepickerstart', 
                                            'required'=>true,
                                            'class' => 'datetimepicker', 
                                            'placeholder' => $petsService->start_date,
                                            'value' => $petsService->start_date]); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 pr-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $this->Form->control('masked_end_date', 
                                            ['name' => 'end_date',
                                            'required'=>true,
                                            'id' => 'datetimepickerend', 
                                            'class' => 'datetimepicker', 
                                            'placeholder' => $petsService->end_date,
                                            'value' => $petsService->end_date]); ?>
        </div>
    </div>               
    <div class="col-md-2 h-100">
        
        <div class="col-12 p-0 m-0">
            <div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <label><?= __('Payed')?></label><br>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <?php 
                echo $this->Form->control('confirmed',[
                                            'label' => '',
                                            'style' => 'transform: scale(1.5); height:40px;',
                                            'class' => 'pl-5'
                                        ]); 
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 h-100 ">
      <div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <label><?= __('More')?></label><br>    
      </div>
      <div id="btn-mas" class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height:50px;">
          <i class="fa fa-plus" onclick="agregar();"></i>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function agregar(){
    $("#hijo").clone().appendTo("#padre");
  }
</script>
```

Funciona bien, ¡me realiza el clone! El problema es que al usar esta función o método se clona todo exactamente igual.
Necesito diferenciar los ID para poder manipularlos luego.
La idea es poder diferenciar los nodos clonados que se crean al dar click en + y tratar esos datos obtenidos.

Comment: No se ve el id del que hablas. No sabemos si es un input, un div, o si ambas cosas una conteniendo a otra. o que es. ¿Podrias agregar el html correspondiente tanto a #padre como #hijo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inténtalo con esto:

```
var contadorHijos = 1;
function agregar() {
  let clonado = $("#hijo").clone()
  clonado.attr("id", "hijo_" + contadorHijos);
  contadorHijos++
  clonado.appendTo("#padre");
}
```

Tal como has solicitado en tus comentarios, ahora se crean con **ids** de forma secuencial.

**Explicación:**

Al quererlo de forma secuencial primero creamos una variable global denominada `contadorHijos` para que nos sirva de contador cada vez que ejecutemos la función `agregar`.

Dentro de la función asignamos a una variable local denominada `clonado` un clon del elemento con id `hijo`. Luego le cambiamos el atributo `id` asignándole el nombre `hijo_` más un número que nos vendrá dado por la variable global `contadorHijos`. Después incrementamos el contador para que la siguiente vez que se invoque a la función `agregar` asigne otro número superior. Y finalmente lo agregamos al elemento con id `padre`.

Comment: coloque la estructura completa en cuestión, para tratar de aclarar un poco más la idea de lo que quiero hacer

Comment: Ya, bueno, mi respuesta sigue siendo válida si lo que quieres es cambiar `#hijo` por lo que sea, pero lo que veo es que se te van a duplicar los id `datetimepickerend`y `datetimepickerend` pero quizás no los uses para nada

Comment: Los data datetimepickerend y datetimepickerend no funcionan por ahora al clonar, pero lo mas importante es diferenciar al clonar 2 o más veces los nodos hijos que se creen, ya que pueden ser más de 2

Comment: Y que ids quieres que tengan?  aleatorios?  secuenciales? Aunque diria que da igual como se llamen los clonados, pues dudo que los uses para nada.  Es recomendable usar distintos id para todo, eso es indudable, pero si te fijas tu siempre vas a clonar a `hijo`, por lo tanto si los otros se repiten da lo mismo a efectos prácticos (o si tienen nombres aleatorios tambien da igual cual sea). O quizas, en lugar de clonar el id del hijo, deberias clonar una clase llamada `hijo` o `hijoPrincipal`, y quitarla en los clonados con el mismo metodo.

Comment: Si usas dos clases, mejor, en plan `class="hijo hijoPrincipal"` y en los clonados le quitas el `.hijoPrincipal` y podras referenciarlos siempre a todos como `.hijo`

Comment: Seria secuencial, ya que en este caso la clonación me agrega unos campos con el onclick, que luego debo almacenar

Comment: Vale, acabo de actualizar mi respuesta con la solución secuencial

Comment: Gracias @masterguru funciona correctamente

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro, acabo de agregar una explicación para dejar la respuesta completa ahora que ya es válida.